# Fix float precision with decimal numbers

Tags: python, rounding

```
a = 1

for x in range(5):
    a += 0.1
    print(a)
```

This is the result:

```
1.1
1.2000000000000002
1.3000000000000003
1.4000000000000004
1.5000000000000004
```

How can I fix this? Is the `round()` function the only way? Can I set the precision of a variable before setting its value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> can i set the precision of a variable before setting the value?

Use the [`decimal`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html) module which, unlike [`float()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=float#float), offers arbitrary precision and can represent decimal numbers exactly:

```
>>> from decimal import Decimal, getcontext
>>> 
>>> getcontext().prec = 5
>>> 
>>> a = Decimal('1')
>>> 
>>> for x in range(5):
...     a += Decimal('0.1')  # note the use of `str` here
...     print(a)
... 
1.1000
1.2000
1.3000
1.4000
1.5000
```

Answer (score 2):

You could format your output like this;

```
a=1
for x in range(5):
    a += 0.1
    print("{:.9f}".format(a) )
```

Answer (score 2):

Formatted output has been duly suggested by @Jaco. However, if you want control of precision in your variable beyond pure output, you might want to look at the `decimal` module.

```
from decimal import Decimal

a = 1
for x in range(3):
    a += Decimal('0.10')  # use string, not float as argument
    # a += Decimal('0.1000')
    print(a)  # a is now a Decimal, not a float

> 1.10  # 1.1000
> 1.20  # 1.2000
> 1.30  # 1.3000
```

Comment: Nice suggestion to use strings as input to `Decimal()`. Somehow I missed that useful functionality.

Comment: @Chris Reading your answer, I have to admit, i didn't know you could set the general precision using get_context :D I had only used the context to set general rounding behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your problem is only displaying the number, @Jaco 's answer does the job. However if you're concern about using that variable and potentially make comparisons or assigning to dictionary keys, I'd say you have to stick to round(). For example this wouldn't work:

```
a = 1
for x in range(5):
    a += 0.1
    print('%.1f' % a)
    if a == 1.3:
        break

1.1
1.2
1.3
1.4
1.5
```

You'd have to do:

```
a = 1
for x in range(5):
    a += 0.1
    print('%.1f' % a)
    if round(a, 1) == 1.3:
        break

1.1
1.2
1.3
```